# Configure Kubernetes cpu memory request and limit for a jenkins slaves created with jenkinsci kubernetes-plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am using [jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) to provision slave pods in my Jenkins builds. I need to specify these pods' cpu and memory limit and request params. It can be done directly in the pipeline configuration, as shown [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-configuration).

However I would prefer to do it directly in the Jenkins configuration (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Kubernetes -> Kubernetes Pod Template.

There is a specific section to insert a mergeable raw yaml:

[image]

How can it be set up there? I have tried but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found and option to configure it hidden under advanced options:

[image]

Comment: Go to: https://jenkins-url/configureClouds or in UI: Manage Nodes and Clouds --> Configure Clouds --> Pod Templates --> Pod Templates details --> Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the memory and CPU of your Jenkins agent (JNLP container) via the Kubernetes plugin [container template yaml](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-container-template).

To change "resourceLimitCpu" and "resourceLimitMemory" values for example:

```
  clouds:
  - kubernetes:
      ...
      name: "kubernetes"
      templates:
      - containers:
        - image: "..."
          name: "jnlp"
          resourceLimitCpu: "1000m"
          resourceLimitMemory: "4000Mi"
          ...
```